# Intuition of Faraday's law at a boundary

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, electromagnetic-induction, boundary-conditions

I know that Faraday's law means that the tangential electric fields have to be equal at both sides of a boundary. I'm struggling to understand intuitively why this has to be the case. What would happen if they weren't equal and why?

Answer (score 1):

If they are not equal, then magnetic field at boundary should be infinite. Consider the following little rectangular loop $\Gamma$ which straddles the boundary.

[image: A boundary condition Ey2=Ey1 is obtained from ∮ΓE⋅ds=0.]

If $E_{y1} \ne E_{y2}$ then we have non-zero electric field circulation in this contour. By Faraday's law of induction the magnetic field flux through this field should be non-zero also. But we can make the rectangle very narrow, so that the loop encloses an infinitesimal area, thus magnetic field should be infinite. See [Feynman Lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_33.html) for details.